# Unique instance of a commonly inherited base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, multiple-inheritance

I've got the following class structure:

```
class Common {
//members and data here.
};

class Derived1 : public Common 
{
};

class Derived2: public Common, public Derived1
{
};
```

As I understand this hierarchy both `Derived1` and `Derived2` will share any members from `Common`.
Is there a way with out making `Derived1` private in `Derived2` to allow `Derived2` to still inherit from `Common` but have separate function overrides.
Basically i need to override a virtual function in `Derived1`, and `Derived2` but still have `Derived1`'s function run (it's a threading api).
Any help apreciated.

Comment: If Derived1 inherits from Common, and Derived2 inherits from Derived1, why does Derived2 also inherit from Common? Isn't this redundant?

Comment: Say `Common` contains the virtual function `virtual void run()`. If you have a `Common&` that refers to an object with the dynamic type `Derived2`, and you call `run()` on that reference, which version of the overridden function do you want to call? By the way - `Derived1` and `Derived2` will not share a single `Common` object. For them to share a single `Common` base object, you would have to virtually inherit from `Common` in both `Derived1` and `Derived2`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Walkerneo points out, you don't need to inherit from both Common and Derived1. You can simply inherit from Derived1 and you'll also get inheritance from Common. You can explicitly call Derived1's method from Derived2's method by doing the following:

```
void Derived2::overriddenMethod ()
{
    // Do something unique here
    Derived1::overriddenMethod ();
    // Maybe do some more stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this even with single inheritance:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual ~Base() { }
};

struct Intermediate : Base
{
    virtual void foo() { /* ... */ }
    // ...
};

struct Derived : Intermediate
{
    virtual void foo()
    {
        Intermediate::foo();
        // new stuff
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using virtual functions for **runtime polymorphism** and assigning a variable of your `Derived2` class to a pointer of `Derived1` class

```
class Common {
//members and data here.
public:
    virtual void commonFunction() = 0; //keeping it pure virtual
};

class Derived1 : public Common 
{
    virtual void commonFunction(){
        //do something in derived1
    }
};

class Derived2: public Common, public Derived1
{
    void commonFunction(){
        //do something in derived2
    }
};
int main(){
    Derived2 derived2;
    Derived1 *derived1;
    derived1 = &derived2;
    derived1->commonFunction(); //calls the common function definition in Derived1 
 /* ... */
}
```